# Spring Boot EHcache cacheResolver

Tags: spring-boot, caching, patch

Use Case:

I have used @Cacheable  product repository

**In ProductRepository.java**

```
@Cacheable(value = "ProductId")
    public ProductEntity findByProductId(long productId);
```

ProductController

1. Get API ( Product Id)
2. Patch API (update the required data)

Product Service
for GET Method

```
@CacheEvict(cacheNames = { "ProductId" }, allEntries = true)

public ProductView getProductByProductId(long productId)
{
productEntity = productRepository.findByProductId(productId);
}
```

**My question is after updating my single product details (using @Patch) how to update cache for single record only while calling Get API for *single Product***

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could declare the save method in your repository:

```
@Override
@CacheEvict(value = "ProductId")
ProductEntity save(ProductEntity product);
```

And call that method on PATCH.